# Firestore Rules coverage report - Request expression never evaluated (Firestore emulator)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Normally I test my security rules for Firestore with the Firestore emulator. Until a few weeks ago, everything worked wonderfully. I changed nothing and now the Firestore emulator is freaking out. I can't use `request` and `resources` anymore.

My Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Test/{testId} {
      allow read, write: if isLoggedIn();
    }

    function isLoggedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null
    }
  }
}
```

If i visit http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/projektName:ruleCoverage.html, I get this message: `Expression never evaluated`

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbduw.png)

`firebase --version`: 8.2.0

Any ideas to fix this Firestore emulator error?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore docs are a bit confusing. They state that the  URL should be:

`http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/<database_name>:ruleCoverage.html`

However, they don't explain what `<database_name>` should be replaced with your `project_id`.  *Yes... reading the URL some might thing is obvious, but is really the argument name that should make it obvious. Plus, in Firestore databases are not created neither accessed by name.*

**SOLUTION:**

`<database_name>` should be replaced by your `project_id` (this value is available in the files `.firebaserc` or `google-services.json`

So, if your `project_id` is `my-amazing-app`, your rulesCoverage url would be: 
`http://localhost:8080/emulator/v1/projects/my-amazing-app:ruleCoverage.html`